# EmailSession in Java Webapp

Tags: java, email

I have written an `EmailSession` class to connect and get (unread) mail messages. It is all working, but I would like to see your opinions on any enhancements or improvements, as I understood there are lots of bad examples on the Internet and I copy-pasted most of it together.

One issue I already noticed:

- If there is no internet connection it throws a `java.net.UnknownHostException` instead of handling the issue gracefully.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class EmailSession {

    private Session session;
    private Store store;
    private Folder inbox;
    private int messageCount;
    private int unreadMessageCount;
    private List<Message> unreadMessages;

    public EmailSession() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", MyProps.getProperty("mail.store.protocol"));
        try {
            session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            store = session.getStore();
            store.connect(MyProps.getProperty("mail.host"), MyProps.getProperty("mail.user"), MyProps.getProperty("mail.password"));
            inbox = store.getFolder(MyProps.getProperty("mail.foldername"));
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
            List<Message> messages;
            if (messageCount > 100) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailSession.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, 
                        "More than 100 messages");
                messages = Arrays.asList(inbox.getMessages(1, 100));
            } else {
                messages = Arrays.asList(inbox.getMessages());
            }
            unreadMessages = new ArrayList<>();
            unreadMessageCount = 0;
            for (Message message : messages) {
                boolean isUnreadMessage = true;
                for (Flags.Flag flag : message.getFlags().getSystemFlags()) {
                    if (flag == Flags.Flag.SEEN) {
                        isUnreadMessage = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isUnreadMessage) {
                    unreadMessages.add(message);
                    unreadMessageCount++;
                }
            }
            inbox.close(true);
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailSession.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailSession.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Folder getInbox() {
        return inbox;
    }

    public int getMessageCount() {
        return messageCount;
    }

    public int getUnreadMessageCount() {
        return unreadMessageCount;
    }

    public List<Message> getUnreadMessages() {
        return unreadMessages;
    }

    public boolean close() {
        try {
            store.close();
            return true;
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailSession.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Pointless member variables

`session` could be a local variable in the constructor. You use it once to get `store` and you don't reference it again.

`unreadMessageCount` is pointless, because you could replace it with `unreadMessages.size()` instead.

In the constructor, you assign `inbox`, but you also close it. I'm not really familiar with how `javax.mail` works, but usually, after you close something it tends to become unusable. If that's the case, then the `inbox` member is pointless.

Pointless member variables make your class design confusing, hard to read, and potentially buggy. Try to be minimalistic, and eliminate anything from your class that it doesn't really need.

#### Extract logger

The logging in your code can be simplified if you extract the `Logger` to a constant:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EmailSession.class.getName());

// ...
LOGGER.warning("More than 100 messages");
// ...
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

#### Extract methods

The constructor is too long. It's hard to read large chunks of code. You could extract some of the functionality there to private methods to make it more readable:

```
private List<Message> getMessages(Folder inbox, int messageCount) throws MessagingException {
    if (messageCount > 100) {
        LOGGER.warning("More than 100 messages");
        return Arrays.asList(inbox.getMessages(1, 100));
    }
    return Arrays.asList(inbox.getMessages());
}

private List<Message> getUnreadMessages(List<Message> messages) throws MessagingException {
    List<Message> unreadMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        boolean isUnreadMessage = true;
        for (Flags.Flag flag : message.getFlags().getSystemFlags()) {
            if (flag == Flags.Flag.SEEN) {
                isUnreadMessage = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isUnreadMessage) {
            unreadMessages.add(message);
        }
    }
    return unreadMessages;
}
```

With these helper methods and the other suggestions above, you could simplify the constructor:

```
public EmailSession() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", MyProps.getProperty("mail.store.protocol"));
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    try {
        store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(MyProps.getProperty("mail.host"), MyProps.getProperty("mail.user"), MyProps.getProperty("mail.password"));
        inbox = store.getFolder(MyProps.getProperty("mail.foldername"));
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
        List<Message> messages = getMessages(inbox, messageCount);
        inbox.close(true);
        unreadMessages = getUnreadMessages(messages);
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I also moved `inbox.close` higher to close it immediately when you don't need it anymore.

#### Avoid wildcard imports

Wildcard imports like `import java.util.*` are [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad). Try to avoid it, it's better to clean up all of these:

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> import java.util.logging.*;
> import javax.mail.*;
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I'd expect a `WhateverSession` to implement `AutoCloseable`, to be usable in a "try-with-resources" statement.

For that you need: Java 7, a void method `close()` to override the `AutoCloseable`

Your class then would look minimally different:

```
public class EmailSession implements AutoCloseable() {

    //all the other stuff.

    @Override
    public void close() {
        store.close();
        //Just bubble exceptions to caller
    }
}
```

Additionally your EmailSession just handles a single user. Assuming one user has multiple e-mail accounts, you can't create a EmailSession nicely. Instead you'd have to expose an different constructor where you pass in all required data to build it.

This means you could then use your EmailSession in a try-with-resources statement as follows:

```
try (EmailSession mailsession = new EmailSession()) {
    //do stuff with mailsession
} /* Exception handling here */
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm the only one who thinks the constructor is too big? Generally, i avoid to let the constructor do many things (just.. create the object and leave!) and prefer static factory and methods to it.

Field `unreadMessageCount` is already 0 by default when you create the object, you don't need `unreadMessageCount = 0;`.

What about one line for save messages?

```
List<Message> messages = Arrays.asList(inbox.getMessages(1, messageCount > 99 ? 100 : messageCount));
```

---

```
private Session session;
```

Is a field, but used only in constructor. It could be a local variable, if `Session.getInstance(props, null)` is an heavy operation you should mark it `static` (and do some other things if it's used in multithread applications).

`store` is used only in constructor, you need it to read data? You do everything in the constructor why you can't close it in the constructor too? After all, when the constructor ends everything is readed from class fields and it's not used anymore.

Comment: Great feedback!

Comment: "I'm the only one who thinks the constructor is too big?"

Oh no you are not! That is untestable.